# Is there any practical difference between curly braces and quotation marks in BIB files?

Tags: bibliographies

Is there any practical difference in doing this:

```
@techreport{Key,
  author = "Sanchez, E.J.",
  ...
}
```

instead of doing this:

```
@techreport{Key,
  author = {Sanchez, E.J.},
  ...
}
```